# How to forbid users to change their first, last and screen names?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress 3.1. I need to forbid users to change their first, last and screen names in their profile, but admin must still have this possibility. How can I do that?

Comment: For specific Wordpress help, it might be worth asking a question on the [Wordpress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask); this does *not* represent a vote-to-close, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only an ideea ... : you can use [validate_username](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/validate_username) filter, then check if the current logged in user is admin, if not then return false if a user is logged in . Same would apply for the user last and screen names .

Comment: I've added `<?php if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) print ('disabled="disabled"') ?>` to input tags.